# Use Auth::user() in api resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel **sanctum** to authenticate and need to access to the **Auth::user()** in **PropertyResource** like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PropertyResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // if auth user make saved true or false,
        // else make'saved' = false key
        return [
            'property' => parent::toArray($request),
            'saved' => Auth::check() ? User::find(Auth::id())->is_saved(parent::toArray($request)['id']) : false,
        ];
    }
}
```

When logged in,**'saved'** must be true or false depending on the property was saved or not.

The problem is I can only access the **Auth::user()** when the route has the **'auth:sanctum'** middleware set.

I'm using this route `Route::get('property', [PropertyController::class, 'index']);`
which has **no auth middleware** and return  all the property.

How can I access to the Auth guard using this route?

Comment: I fixed it for now using two routes, one when no user logged in and the second if the user is logged since I can only access the auth guard with authenticate route.

**First route**
`Route::get('property', [PropertyController::class, 'index']);`

**Second route**
`Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('auth-property', [PropertyController::class, 'index']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Auth::check() with sanctum, you have two options:

1. Set sanctum as default guard in auth.php config.
2. Use Auth::guard('sanctum')->check() instead of Auth check. And if you want laravel to continue with sanctum you can use: Auth::shouldUse('sanctum').

I had the situation once when in a route I had guests along with authenticated users. I Created a middleware and put a code like this in it:

```
if (auth()->guard('sanctum')->check()) {
        auth()->shouldUse('sanctum');
        return $next($request);
    }
```